# How can I insert variable values into my database in SQLite?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I've somehow managed to insert the contents of a text field using the text fields id with the following code but would rather assign whatever is in the text field to a variable and then insert the value of that variable.

```
var newName = document.getElementById("txNewName").value;
var ing1 = document.getElementById("txIngredient1").value;
var ing2 = document.getElementById("txIngredient2").value;
var ing3 = document.getElementById("txIngredient3").value;

db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyRecipes(MyRecipeName, MyIngredient1, MyIngredient2, MyIngredient3) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[$('#txNewName').val(), $('#txIngredient1').val(), $('#txIngredient2').val(), $('#txIngredient3').val()]);
});
```

I'm using SQLite if that makes a difference and am very new to it so would appreciate any help.

Comment: As another aside, you are mixing javascript and jquery - better to stick to jquery syntax if you are using it.

Answer (score 0):

In the code as given, your variables are declared in a different scope - so within the function the values wouldn't be known. You either need to use global variables, or pass them as parameters. Below I changed the answer to put them inside the function. This may not be what you want, but it will confirm where the problem is:

```
db.transaction(function(transaction) {
    var newName = document.getElementById("txNewName").value;
    var ing1 = document.getElementById("txIngredient1").value;
    var ing2 = document.getElementById("txIngredient2").value;
    var ing3 = document.getElementById("txIngredient3").value;
console.log('Inserting into the database ' + newName + ',' + ing1 +',' + ing2 + ',' + ing3);
    transaction.executeSql('INSERT INTO MyRecipes(MyRecipeName, MyIngredient1, MyIngredient2, MyIngredient3) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',[newName, ing1, ing2, ing3]);
});
```

Comment: Yes I have, the database just displays 'undefined undefined undefined undefined', like with most methods I've tried. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Yes, well in the code as given, your variables are declared in a different scope - so within the function the values wouldn't be known. You either need to use global variables, or pass them as parameters. I changed the answer to put them inside the function. This may not be what you want, but it will confirm where the problem is.

Comment: Of course, thanks, but I've tried both making the variables global, and passing them as parameters but the database is still showing 'undefined undefined undefined undefined'.

Comment: Debugging 101: Check the values before the insert (see log statement I added). You should also check that the `executeSql` didn't raise an error. Are you clearing the table each time, or using defferent values to avoid duplicates?

Comment: The log shows the correct values and there are no errors. The only thing I can think of that could be the issue is the insert statement. I am dropping the database before each attempt. Thank you for the advice on debugging though!